# Mongo: how project a boolean if 'today' is between two date fields?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I've a collection where docs have this fields

```
"new_from" : ISODate("2019-07-08T00:00:00.000+0000"), 
"new_to" : ISODate("2019-07-21T23:59:59.000+0000"),
```

I'd like to project a new field called `new` that *simply* should be true (or 1, or "1") if the today's date is between `new_from` and `new_to`

Is it possible to calculate today's date inside a projection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below [**`$project`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) stage

```
const todaysDate = moment().toDate()

{ "$project": {
  "boolean": {            
    "$and": [
      { "$gte": ["$new_from", todaysDate] },
      { "$lte": ["$new_to", todaysDate] }
    ]
  }
}}
```

Comment: what is todaysDate here? I need to live calculate it

Comment: Updated my answer. It's current time

Answer (score 0):

You can use below $project with $cond

```
{
            $project: {
                new:
                {
                    if: {
                        $and: [
                            { $lt: ['$new_to', new Date()] },
                            { $gt: ['$new_from', new Date()] },
                          }
                        ]
                    },
                    then:true,
                    else:false
                }
            }
        },
```